# Flutter method missing from final variable

Tags: flutter

Using navigation and routing example from flutter, I changed a little bit the code to be able to display data from a JSON, instead of hard codded values. I thing that it comes from the fact that `loadJsonData` is an async function.

The console error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building GamesScreen(dirty, dependencies:
[RouteStateScope, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#a13d8]], state: _GamesScreenState#882e7(ticker
inactive)):
Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance getter 'allGames'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
Tried calling: allGames
```

`games.dart` (previously `screens/books.dart`)

```
body: TabBarView(
  controller: _tabController,
  children: [
    GameList(
      games: libraryInstance.popularGames,
      onTap: _handleGameTapped,
    ),
    GameList(
      games: libraryInstance.newGames,
      onTap: _handleGameTapped,
    ),
    GameList(
      games: libraryInstance.allGames,
      onTap: _handleGameTapped,
    ),
  ],
)
```

`library.dart`

```
final libraryInstance = Library().loadJsonData();
  /*..addGame(
      isNew: true)*/

class Library {
  List<Game> allGames = [];
  final List<Session> allSessions = [];

  loadJsonData() async {
    String jsonData = await rootBundle.loadString('lib/src/assets/json/games.json');
    log(jsonData);
    //setState(() {
      allGames = await json.decode(jsonData).map<Game>((dataPoint) => Game.fromJson(dataPoint)).toList();
    //});
  }

  List<Game> get popularGames => [
        ...allGames.where((game) => game.wished > 1),
      ];

  List<Game> get newGames => [
        ...allGames.where((game) => game.isNew),
      ];
}
```

Comment: Your problem is in this line: `final libraryInstance = Library().loadJsonData();` You create am instance of Library, call its loadJsonData method, which returns a future and assign *that* to `libraryInstance`. You could change this (using cascade) to: `final libraryInstance = Library()..loadJsonData();` - note the extra dot. This makes an instance of Library, assigns that to `libraryInstance` and then calls load json data. Note that allGames will be empty until the async function completes. This is where you would then use setState - of which you will learn more as you explore.